# CloudPanel installation is not successful

Tags: debian

This is what i am getting when I install CloudPanel on Debian 10.

```
    cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/sbin/clp-nginx': Text file busy
    dpkg: error processing package cloudpanel (--configure):
     installed cloudpanel package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     cloudpanel
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    
    
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The installation of CloudPanel is complete!
    
    CloudPanel can be accessed now:
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It shows as installation completed. But CloudPanel access url does not come.

How I can sort it or remove CloudPanel. [I cannot find a way to uninstall the cloudpanel.]

Comment: Getting the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: Switch to aaPanel. It is just amazing!

Comment: so you don't have a solution?


I already migrated from aapanel to cloudpanel

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind of late but hope this helps.

However,I apoligize because I didn't fully document how I uninstall cloudpanel (I was just trying random things).

**---WARNING. READ BEFORE RUNNING STEP 1--- First step could cause more problems and you'll probably get a bunch of errors more.**

**NOTE: I rebooted many times, maybe rebooting it after every step could help**

1 . My first step was to find where cloudpanel was located and then I removed /tmp/cloudpanel and /usr/share/doc/cloudpanel

```
dpkg -L cloudpanel
sudo rm -rf /tmp/cloudpanel
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/cloudpanel
```

After that I remember I tried to run sudo apt remove cloudpanel but that just caused more problems and I don't really think this helped me at all but I add this step here just to let you know all what I did.

2 . I moved to /home and remove every possible folder created by cloudpanel

```
sudo rm -rf /home/clp 
sudo rm -rf /home/mysql
```

3 . After rebooting I deleted the user created by cloudpanel.

```
sudo userdel clp
```

In the case that you are not able to delete the user try rebooting again and/or killing all processes by clp.

```
sudo killall --user clp && sudo userdel clp
```

4 . Remove cloudpanel from sudoers

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/sudoers.d/cloudpanel
```

5. Delete cloudpanel's info from dpkg and configure dpkg

   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/cloudpanel
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
6. Now you should be able to uninstall cloudpanel

   sudo apt remove cloudpanel
   sudo apt autoremove

I don't know what exactly did it and I don't really think sped 1 is required.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error because there are some services that will take the hostname to configure specifically mail, so it will give an error, you need to change the HOSTNAME Server to a resolvable domain then go to the docs install CloudPanel and configure it in the direction guide.

Answer (score -1):

terminate and relaunch a new blank vm

see here https://discordapp.com/channels/696694788883349574/696697364114702368/975695566744993842

[Reply from the sole developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1vJS.png)